# Why a large force is required to rotate a wheel at 60 rpm than that required to rotate it at 1500 rpm?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I am assuming that i have a wheel of say 1 m radius. And it requires 10 hp(horsepower) to operate.
I found out that 
`hp= (Torque x rpm)/5252`
So i am considering the case for rpm 60 and rpm 1500
for rpm 60:
`10 = (T x 60)/5252`
`T= 875 N-m`

and for rpm 1500 it comes out to be
`T= 35.01 N-m`

then we know that 
`torque= (radius)(force)sin(theta)`
taking theta to be 90 degree
the formula becomes
`torque= (radius)(force)`

so force for the 60 rpm case:
`f= 875/1 = 875 N`

and for rpm 1500 the force comes out to be `35.01 N`

I want to know why is it so that in order to rotate with higher rpm we require less force than to rotate the same wheel with higher rpm. As apparently to me it appears that for achieving higher rpm one must apply higher force.
Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere as i am at a very initial state of learning physics.

Comment: Your puzzling result arises from your puzzling assumption that your wheel always requires 10 hp, at whatever speed it is turning. I assume that the power is needed because of resistive torques acting on the wheel. In that case the faster you turn the wheel the more work per second has to be done against these forces, so the greater the power needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the thing here is that you are fixing the power to be $10$ HP. As you say, the power may be calcuated as $P = \tau \, \omega$, and since $|\tau| = |F||R|$ we get $|P| = |F|\,|R|\,\omega$. So, if you fix $P$ now the only thing you can do is decrease $|F|$ to get a larger $\omega$.

I guess your intuition fails here because to increase the force applied while keeping the power constant, the speed must decrease and so does $\omega$.

Comment: so does an alternator comes for different hp.